# Can't set values to INTran.LotSerialNbr or INTran.ExpireDate

Tags: acumatica

I have a need to set the LotSerialNbr and ExpireDate on INTran records when entering an inventory receipt on screen IN301000.

Also, the FieldDefaulting events for INTran.LotSerialNbr and INTran.ExpireDate are triggered as expected, yet FieldUpdated events for those two fields don't get hit.

Simple code that just tries to set the values, such as what's below, doesn't seem to work.  I've also tried the INTranSplit records, but those events don't get hit either.

I'm sure I'm missing something, so any insight would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.BQL;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.Common.Extensions;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.IN;

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
  public class INReceiptEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<INReceiptEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    protected void INTran_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
      var row = (INTran)e.Row;
      if (row == null) return;

      row.LotSerialNbr = "TESTING";
      row.ExpireDate = Convert.ToDateTime("12/31/2021");
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `lotSerialNbr` and `expireDate` fields seem to be in a world of their own.  I was able to finally get them to take some values for my needs, so I'll share what I've done here in hopes that if someone else gets stuck, this may get them headed in the right direction, or that if I did something wrong, someone can correct me.

I am using `FieldSelecting` events to set the default values for the lot and expiration dates as the `InventoryID` field is populated at this time whereas it is null during `FieldDefaulting`, and I need the `InventoryID` in order to get the item and lot classes.

I am using the `Base.lsselect.SetValueExt<>()` method to set the value as well as setting an `e.ReturnValue` as without one or the other, it seems you get mixed results in the UI where the value is in the cache, but not presented on the screen.

When it comes time to save, if you have typed a date into the Expire Date or Lot fields, then those values are propagated through the UI to the views as expected, however, if you don't type in a value, for whatever reason, the values we set during `FieldSelecting` do not get copied from the views to the `INTranSplit` record when it's being created.  This is why I have added the `FieldDefatulting` events for the two fields on the `INTranSplit` record, so that they default to the same values (via the same logic), in the event the user didn't actually type in the values.

This logic seems to be working in the `INReceiptEntry`, `POReceiptEntry` and `MoveEntry` graphs.

Again, if there's a better way, or a "correct" way to default the `ExpireDate` and `LotSerialNbr` fields, please post a corrected answer.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.BQL;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.Common.Extensions;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.IN;

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
    public class INReceiptEntry_ExtensionCST : PXGraphExtension<INReceiptEntry>
    {
        public static bool IsActive() => true;

        #region Event Handlers
        protected void _(Events.FieldSelecting<INTran.lotSerialNbr> e)
        {
            INTran row = (INTran)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;

            InventoryItem item = InventoryItem.PK.Find(Base, row.InventoryID);

            if (item != null && (item.LotSerClassID ?? "").Trim().ToUpper() == "TEST")
            {
                Base.lsselect.SetValueExt<INTran.lotSerialNbr>(Base.transactions.Current, "TESTING");
                e.ReturnValue = "TESTING";
            }
        }
        protected void _(Events.FieldDefaulting<INTranSplit.lotSerialNbr> e)
        {
            INTranSplit row = (INTranSplit)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;

            InventoryItem item = InventoryItem.PK.Find(Base, row.InventoryID);

            if (item != null && (item.LotSerClassID ?? "").Trim().ToUpper() == "TEST")
            {
                e.NewValue = "TESTING";
            }
        }
        protected void _(Events.FieldSelecting<INTran.expireDate> e)
        {
            INTran row = (INTran)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;
            if (row.InventoryID == null) return;

            InventoryItem item = InventoryItem.PK.Find(Base, row.InventoryID);

            if (item != null)
            {
                INItemClass itemClass = INItemClass.PK.Find(Base, item.ItemClassID);

                if (itemClass != null (itemClass.ItemClassCD ?? "").Trim().ToUpper() == "TEST" && row.ExpireDate == null)
                {
                   DateTime expire = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);
                   Base.lsselect.SetValueExt<INTran.expireDate>(Base.transactions.Current, expire);
                   e.ReturnValue = expire;
                }
            }
        }
        protected void _(Events.FieldDefaulting<INTranSplit.expireDate> e)
        {
            INTranSplit row = (INTranSplit)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;
            if (row.InventoryID == null) return;

            InventoryItem item = InventoryItem.PK.Find(Base, row.InventoryID);

            if (item != null)
            {
                INItemClass itemClass = INItemClass.PK.Find(Base, item.ItemClassID);

                if (itemClass != null (itemClass.ItemClassCD ?? "").Trim().ToUpper() == "TEST" && row.ExpireDate == null)
                {

                   DateTime expire = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);
                   e.NewValue = expire;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```